# What is an efficient way to calculate user points with many foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I need to calculate user's point based on some factors of the articles they posted. It's a cron job which runs every hour.

Currently, this is how I did:

1. Get the list of user who have posted at least 1 article (to narrow the list)
2. For each user, select his/her article from database (foreach loop) and do the calculation. Then update his/her point to database.

Basically, it's like:

```
$userList = getList();

foreach ($userList as $user)
{
    $articleList = getArticles($user);
    $point = 0;
    foreach ($articleList as $article)
    {
        // Do calculation here
    }
    updateUserPoint($point);
}
```

This works correctly. But, when you come to large database (>10k users and > 100k articles), this script runs slower and slower because the lists are getting longer and these loops take longer time. The number of MySQL queries also increases rapidly.

Please help me a good way to do this. I think mine is not efficient and good enough.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you please share the table structures with some sample data?

Comment: @Code-Monk: Thanks for your time. Please find the sample data via this link: http://pastebin.com/9CG4ZHnF. Just import and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

need to change your code in getArticles function and query should use sum and group by user_id together to get sum of points for that particular user and then need to update point with that user id in function updateUserPoint function.

if you provide me getArticals function complete, I will change that to get sum of points for that particular user and then you can use it to update.